# Remove URL query parameter if no value exists

Tags: php, wordpress, filter, custom-post-type, taxonomy

I [found this bit of very useful code](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/105115/filter-custom-post-type-using-multiple-taxonomy-dropdowns) for generating a dropdown to use as a URL query string for multiple custom taxonomies.

The code below, paired with a bunch of `if(isset($_GET['taxonomies']))` and `if(empty($_GET['taxonomies']))` declarations in PHP in the `archive.php` file, sort of works in filtering posts across three custom taxonomies.

However, it only works if URL query parameters are not empty. For instance:

```
example.com/custom-post-type-slug/?taxonomy1=term1&taxonomy2=termA&taxonomy3=termZ
```

... works just fine.

```
example.com/custom-post-type-slug/?taxonomy1=term1&taxonomy2=termA
```

... also works fine.

However, the dropdown created by the code below will generate a URL query string that includes empty query parameters such as:

```
example.com/custom-post-type-slug/?taxonomy1=term1&taxonomy2=&taxonomy3=termZ
```

The empty query parameter for taxonomy 2 breaks it. As does all query parameters missing:

```
example.com/custom-post-type-slug/?taxonomy1=&taxonomy2=&taxonomy3=
```

**How do I tweak the code below to remove the URL query parameter if there's no value?**

The most ideal situation is that if there's no URL query value, the query parameter is removed from the string. How do I do that with this code?

This is in my functions.php file.

```
function get_terms_dropdown_taxonomy1($taxonomies, $args){
            $myterms = get_terms($taxonomies, $args);
            $output ="<select name='taxonomy1'>";
            $output .="<option value=''>All Taxonomy 1</option>";
            foreach($myterms as $term){
                    $root_url = get_bloginfo('url');
                    $term_taxonomy=$term->taxonomy;
                    $term_slug=$term->slug;
                    $term_name =$term->name;
                    $link = $term_slug;
                    $output .="<option value='".$link."'>".$term_name."</option>";
            }
            $output .="</select>";
    return $output;
    }

function get_terms_dropdown_taxonomy2($taxonomies, $args){
            $myterms = get_terms($taxonomies, $args);
            $output ="<select name='taxonomy2'>";
            $output .="<option value=''>All Taxonomy 2</option>";
            foreach($myterms as $term){
                    $root_url = get_bloginfo('url');
                    $term_taxonomy=$term->taxonomy;
                    $term_slug=$term->slug;
                    $term_name =$term->name;
                    $link = $term_slug;
                    $output .="<option value='".$link."'>".$term_name."</option>";
            }
            $output .="</select>";
    return $output;
    }

function get_terms_dropdown_taxonomy3($taxonomies, $args){
            $myterms = get_terms($taxonomies, $args);
            $output ="<select name='taxonomy3'>";
            $output .="<option value=''>All Taxonomy 3</option>";
            foreach($myterms as $term){
                    $root_url = get_bloginfo('url');
                    $term_taxonomy=$term->taxonomy;
                    $term_slug=$term->slug;
                    $term_name =$term->name;
                    $link = $term_slug;
                    $output .="<option value='".$link."'>".$term_name."</option>";
            }
            $output .="</select>";
    return $output;
    }
```

Meanwhile, this is output within a template file.

```
        <?php
            $taxonomies = array('taxonomy1');
            $args = array('orderby'=>'name','hide_empty'=>1);
            $select = get_terms_dropdown_taxonomy1($taxonomies, $args);
            $select = preg_replace("#<select([^>]*)>#", "<select$1 id='taxonomy1' class='dropdown' aria-label='Select a taxonomy 1'>", $select);
            echo $select;
        ?>

        <?php
            $taxonomies = array('taxonomy2');
            $args = array('orderby'=>'name','hide_empty'=>1);
            $select = get_terms_dropdown_taxonomy2($taxonomies, $args);
            $select = preg_replace("#<select([^>]*)>#", "<select$1 id='taxonomy2' class='dropdown' aria-label='Select a taxonomy 2'>", $select);
            echo $select;
        ?>

        <?php
            $taxonomies = array('taxonomy3');
            $args = array('orderby'=>'name','hide_empty'=>1);
            $select = get_terms_dropdown_taxonomy3($taxonomies, $args);
            $select = preg_replace("#<select([^>]*)>#", "<select$1 id='taxonomy3' class='dropdown' aria-label='Select a taxonomy 3'>", $select);
            echo $select;
        ?>
```

**EDIT: Thanks to your help here is the final working code.**

```
<?php
$url = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

    // WORKING | all taxonomy1, taxonomy2, and taxonomy3; no values for any taxonomy; displays six most recent posts

    if(empty($_GET['taxonomy1']) && empty($_GET['taxonomy2']) && empty($_GET['taxonomy3'])) {

    $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? absint( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) : 1; $exec_query = new WP_Query( array (
        'post_type'         => 'custom_post_type',
        'publish_status'    => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page'    => 6,
        'paged'             => $paged,
    ) );
    }

    // WORKING | taxonomy1 only; no values for taxonomy2 or taxonomy3

    elseif(empty($_GET['taxonomy2']) && empty($_GET['taxonomy3'])) {

    $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? absint( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) : 1; $exec_query = new WP_Query( array (
        'post_type'         => 'custom_post_type',
        'publish_status'    => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page'    => 6,
        'paged'             => $paged,
                    'tax_query'         => array(
                        array(
                            'taxonomy'  => 'taxonomy1',
                            'field'     => 'slug',
                            'terms'     => $_GET['taxonomy1'],
                            'operator'  => 'IN',
                        ),
                    ),
    ) );
    }

    // WORKING | issue only; no values for taxonomy1 or taxonomy3; displays six most recent taxonomy2 posts

    elseif(empty($_GET['taxonomy1']) && empty($_GET['taxonomy3'])) {

    $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? absint( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) : 1; $exec_query = new WP_Query( array (
        'post_type'         => 'custom_post_type',
        'publish_status'    => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page'    => 6,
        'paged'             => $paged,
                    'tax_query'         => array(
                        array(
                            'taxonomy'  => 'taxonomy2',
                            'field'     => 'slug',
                            'terms'     => $_GET['taxonomy2'],
                            'operator'  => 'IN',
                        ),
                    ),
    ) );
    }

    // WORKING | taxonomy3 only; no values for taxonomy1 or taxonomy2

    elseif(empty($_GET['taxonomy1']) && empty($_GET['taxonomy2'])) {

    $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? absint( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) : 1; $exec_query = new WP_Query( array (
        'post_type'         => 'custom_post_type',
        'publish_status'    => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page'    => 6,
        'paged'             => $paged,
                    'tax_query'         => array(
                        array(
                            'taxonomy'  => 'taxonomy3',
                            'field'     => 'slug',
                            'terms'     => $_GET['taxonomy3'],
                            'operator'  => 'IN',
                        ),
                    ),
    ) );
    }   

    // WORKING | taxonomy2 in taxonomy3; no values for taxonomy1

    elseif(empty($_GET['taxonomy1'])) {

    $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? absint( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) : 1; $exec_query = new WP_Query( array (
        'post_type'         => 'custom_post_type',
        'publish_status'    => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page'    => 6,
        'paged'             => $paged,
                    'tax_query'         => array(
                        'relation'      => 'AND',
                        array(
                            'taxonomy'  => 'taxonomy2',
                            'field'     => 'slug',
                            'terms'     => $_GET['taxonomy2'],
                            'operator'  => 'IN',
                        ),
                        array(
                            'taxonomy'  => 'taxonomy3',
                            'field'     => 'slug',
                            'terms'     => $_GET['taxonomy3'],
                            'operator'  => 'IN',
                        ),
                    ),
    ) );
    }

    // WORKING | taxonomy1 in taxonomy3; no values for taxonomy2

    elseif(empty($_GET['taxonomy2'])) {

    $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? absint( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) : 1; $exec_query = new WP_Query( array (
        'post_type'         => 'custom_post_type',
        'publish_status'    => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page'    => 6,
        'paged'             => $paged,
                    'tax_query'         => array(
                        'relation'      => 'AND',
                        array(
                            'taxonomy'  => 'taxonomy1',
                            'field'     => 'slug',
                            'terms'     => $_GET['taxonomy1'],
                            'operator'  => 'IN',
                        ),
                        array(
                            'taxonomy'  => 'taxonomy3',
                            'field'     => 'slug',
                            'terms'     => $_GET['taxonomy3'],
                            'operator'  => 'IN',
                        ),
                    ),
    ) );
    }

    // WORKING | taxonomy1 on taxonomy2; no values for taxonomy3

    elseif(empty($_GET['taxonomy3'])) {

    $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? absint( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) : 1; $exec_query = new WP_Query( array (
        'post_type'         => 'custom_post_type',
        'publish_status'    => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page'    => 6,
        'paged'             => $paged,
                    'tax_query'         => array(
                        'relation'      => 'AND',
                        array(
                            'taxonomy'  => 'taxonomy1',
                            'field'     => 'slug',
                            'terms'     => $_GET['taxonomy1'],
                            'operator'  => 'IN',
                        ),
                        array(
                            'taxonomy'  => 'taxonomy2',
                            'field'     => 'slug',
                            'terms'     => $_GET['taxonomy2'],
                            'operator'  => 'IN',
                        ),
                    ),
    ) );
    }

elseif(isset($_GET['taxonomy1']) && ($_GET['taxonomy2']) && ($_GET['taxonomy3'])) {

$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? absint( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) : 1; $exec_query = new WP_Query( array (
    'post_type'         => 'custom_post_type',
    'publish_status'    => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page'    => 6,
    'paged'             => $paged,
                'tax_query'         => array(
                    'relation'      => 'AND',
                    array(
                        'taxonomy'  => 'taxonomy1',
                        'field'     => 'slug',
                        'terms'     => $_GET['taxonomy1'],
                        'operator'  => 'IN',
                    ),
                    array(
                        'taxonomy'  => 'taxonomy2',
                        'field'     => 'slug',
                        'terms'     => $_GET['taxonomy2'],
                        'operator'  => 'IN',
                    ),
                    array(
                        'taxonomy'  => 'taxonomy3',
                        'field'     => 'slug',
                        'terms'     => $_GET['taxonomy3'],
                        'operator'  => 'IN',
                    ),
                ),
) );
}

    else{

    $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? absint( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) : 1; $exec_query = new WP_Query( array (
        'post_type'         => 'custom_post_type',
        'publish_status'    => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page'    => 6,
        'paged'             => $paged,
    ) );
    }

    if ( $exec_query->have_posts() ) { ?><?php while ( $exec_query->have_posts() ): $exec_query->the_post(); ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`isset()` will return `true` if your query parameter *exists*. It sounds like your code assumes that if the parameter exists, it also contains some useful value. That's not what `isset()` checks.

In this case, [the `empty()` function](https://secure.php.net/empty) is probably what you're looking for. This will return `true` if a variable does **not** exist or if it contains a false-y value such as the empty string you're getting.

Changing your `if`-statement to `if (!empty($_GET['taxonomies']))` should do the trick.

Keep in mind that the string `"0"` is also considered false-y and thus "empty", so if that's a valid value for one of your query parameters you'll need to add an explicit check for that.

Comment: @Matt From your pastebin sample, if all three parameters are provided but empty, none if your `elseif` statements should be hit because the `isset` checks in the first `if` will still return true.

Comment: Updated thread with partially working code. Any idea why two of the clauses are not working?

Comment: @Matt incorrect parentheses placement on `if(empty($_GET['taxonomy1']) && empty($_GET['taxonomy2'] && empty($_GET['taxonomy3']))) {` -- you're not closing `empty()` for taxonomy2 in the correct place.

Comment: jfc... as you can tell I've been staring at this way too long. Thank you! That solved it. Will update the thread with the finished code for others.

Answer (score 0):

To illustrate what the @rickdenhaan said, here are some examples:

```
// Check if $variable is empty, using empty($variable)

$variable = ""; // true
$variable = " "; // false
$variable = 0; // true
$variable = 1; // false
$variable = null; // true
$variable = false; // true

// Check if $variable was defined, using isset($variable)

$variable = ""; // true
$variable = " "; // true
$variable = 0; // true
$variable = 1; // true
$variable = null; // false
$variable = false; // true
```

Curiosity:
As described in the documentation, the `empty()` function is essentially:

```
(!isset($variable) || $variable == false)
```